# How to debug why pending stage is in the unknown state?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark batch job, which reads some json files writes them to Hive and then queries some other Hive tables, does computation and writes output in Orc format back to Hive.

What I experience is job gets stuck with one stage in pending state.
[image: pending stage]

The DAG looks as follows:
[image: DAG]
I'm using `Hadoop 2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292` and Spark is running on YARN.

I looked at the yarn logs, spark event logs, but do not see an issue.
Just rerunning the job results in same behavior.

The question is: what unknown state in stage means, how to debug why job is in it ?

Comment: Is that stage the last stage of the job, generally the last stage is where if your job/query or logic has some issues it fails. The executor logs should give you more insights.

Comment: There is not nearly enough info in your question for any meaningful guess. For starters, can you post your job's DAG?

Comment: @mazaneicha I was looking more for a general approach, nonetheless I updated the question with DAG info. If anything else is required just let me know.

Comment: For a general approach to debugging this you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58574186/4540147) answer

Comment: Sorry, I assumed by showing us a specific stage you had been looking for solution to a particular issue, not a discussion on general troubleshooting techniques.