# Spark processing json data with hundreds of colums

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, multiple-columns

I am doing a POC for Spark application in scala in LOCAL mode. I need to process a json dataset, with 300 columns but only fewer records. We are using Spark SQL and our program runs perfectly fine for 30 - 40 columns in the dataset. We are doing inner joins and outer joins using Spark SQL and other conditions in Where clause. The problem is the SQL is not executing for 300 columns join, its just stuck. Not sure how to analyze the SQL. Is there is solution to this problem without having to run it in distributed mode? Would doing in inner join on the dfs alleviate the problem. Something like this, df1.join(df2, col("id1") == col("id2"), "inner").

Thanks

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562013/why-pyspark-jobs-are-dying-out-in-the-middle-of-process-without-any-particular-e/58574186#58574186) answer, if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide some sample code/ how the Json looks / How do you know spark app is just 'stuck'

Without looking into how much **nested** your json is , generally you can create a hash like **sha256** on **concatenating** all 300 columns (and accounting for **nulls** ) and then join on the hash value.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Json data s an array of flat objects, no nested levels. I am able to say its stuck, because I added some logs, and nothing past the query execution are being logged. I am only joining by single column, the key column. Do I still need to concatenate all the columns and hash?

Comment: There can be multiple resons. Most common one is process dying during Shuffle Read/Write as your local space is eaten too much.
Try with these configs and see what happens ?
```
--conf spark.hadoop.yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled=false \
     --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false \
     --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage=98.0 \```